# JDK и Android Studio/Kotlin (Linux Mint 19.3)

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, kotlin

товарищи. Объясните, кто нибудь, какой JDK нужен сейчас, для разработки под Android? В интернетах у каждого свое мнение. Кто то говорит, что нужен Oracle JDK 8. Кто то говорит, что OpenJDK достаточно.
На данный момент у меня на машине стоит Linux Mint 19.3 (Из всех линуксов именно этот мне понравился). В нем же стоит Open JDK 11. Так вот. Достаточно ли этого, что бы без проблем кодить на Kotlin, в частности, под Android?
Пока в процессе обучения и Open JDK работает нормально. Но, хотелось бы знать наверняка, какая версия JDK "правильная".
Спасибо.

P.S. Насколько мне известно, из за судебных тяжб с oracle, google отказалась от их софта, и тоже сидит на open JDK. Уже как пару лет, если память не изменяет. К чему тогда ставить Oracle JDK 8?

Comment: Используйте что душе угодно. Вероятность получить баги из-за версии Java при разработке под андроид стремится к нулю. А так да - лучше OpenJDK, т.к. точно не будет проблем с лицензией (которых и так не будет, ибо до разработчика докапываться никто не будет)

Comment: Спасибо большое за прояснение)